# Loading pages with Jquery data-role="page"

Tags: jquery, html, pageload

I am working on a web app right now that uses Jquery and has multiple pages on a single html document. This is done through a series of `data-role="page"`s wrapped in `<div>` tags.

Right now, that is only 5 of these 'pages' but I plan to have ~900 (1 for every item that can be reviewed). My question is, does Jquery load all the 'pages' in the html file at once onload?

I'm thinking if it does, it isnt feasible for me to go about this web-app this way, as I'll have 900 pages loaded with 900 calls to a database to populate each with reviews as soon as the html file is loaded.

I thought I might ask before I go too far into the project. Thanks all!

---

UPDATE

I will know where the user will click next. I did some research and think I found a piece of code I believe does it. pastebin.com/JpGW5PqN its line 15-20. Will this work to load the div with id 180336 on line 50? I don't know how to check if it is loaded dynamically or not!

Comment: Why don't you use $.ajax to dynamically load each page when required ?

Answer (score 0):

As it’s still a simple HTML page, then yes, all of those DIV’s are loaded on the first load. There are different ways about going with this, but the most obvious one would be to use $.ajax to load the pages when you need them. Preloading all pages will make everything very slow.

What you can do to optimize, is that in some cases you might know where the user will click/navigate next and you can preload that content while the user is viewing your current one.

Comment: I will know where the user will click next. I did some research and think I found a piece of code I believe does it. http://pastebin.com/JpGW5PqN its line 15-20. Will this work to load the div with id 180336 on line 50? I don't know how to check if it is loaded dynamically or not!

Answer (score 0):

Like margusholland mentioned, you may want to do partial load on this. Otherwise you have 900 AJAX requests. 
Either load 1-10 pages or interact with scroll loading more whenever [user scrolls down](http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/load-content-while-scrolling-with-jquery/) the page.